# ture is not printing

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, async-await

Есть программа, которая двигает квадрат на фоне.

Естьч асть, кода в которой с помощью await сначлаа должен выводится контент в goLeft() функции, а потом true, но true не принтится, только контент goLeft() функции.

Вот кусок кода отвечающий за это:

```
async function promise(){
        let go = goLeft()

        let result = true
        result = await go;
        console.log(result)

    }
```

Comment: ты перетираешь  значение переменной  и ожидаешь вывод true.. не странно ли ?

Comment: Даже если её не перетирать и написать что-то вроде этого: 
``
let go = await goLeft()
console.log(go)
console.log(true)
``
,то всё равно не работает

Comment: Это неправда.... пруф `async function f() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("готово!"), 1000)
  });

  let result = await promise;

  console.log(result);
  console.log(true);
}

f();`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-flower-zm8ffo?file=/src/index.js  (код выше, только в песочнице)

Comment: `let go = await goLeft()`